# Style wp_list_categories

Tags: categories

I think this is a fairly simple question and im sorry if it is but how would I add a `<div>` to each individual category within this code:

```
    <?php
$taxonomy = 'category';
// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
// separator between links
$separator = ',';

if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms;
}   
?>
```

I want to add  `<div class="btn-standard">` to each category. Please note that I only want to display the categories relavent to the post.

Comment: Why have u  defined the param `style` as `yes`

Comment: that was a accident

Comment: is meant to be none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$output = '';
if($categories) {
    $output = "<ul>";
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $output .= '<li><div class="btn-standard"><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a></div></li>';
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
}
echo $output;
```

You can check [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) for more reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach instead

```
 $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
 $count = count($terms);
 if ( $count > 0 ){
     echo "<ul>";
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo "<li><div>" . $term->name . "</div></li>";
     }
     echo "</ul>";
 }
```

Comment: That approach shows all the categories. I need to show only the ones associated with the post